# The argument type 'Function?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?'

Tags: flutter, components, shared

I need to create a shared component but this error appears

> <The argument type 'Function?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String)?>

although I changed Function type into `VoidCallback` type but it didn't work,
please help

```dart
Widget defaultFormField({
       required TextEditingController controller,
       required String label,
       required TextInputType type,
       required VoidCallback validate,
       Function? onSubmit,
       required IconData prefix}) => 
       onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit,
       validator: validate,
       controller: controller,
       keyboardType: type,    
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `onSubmit` as `Function(String)?`. Try this:

```
Widget defaultFormField({
       required TextEditingController controller,
       required String label,
       required TextInputType type,
       required VoidCallback validate,
       Function(String)? onSubmit,
       required IconData prefix}) => 
       onFieldSubmitted: onSubmit,
       validator: validate,
       controller: controller,
       keyboardType: type,    
);
```

Comment: thanks a lot 
but this solved the on onsubmit Function error 
and validate Function error still exist.

Comment: Replace VoidCallback with String? Function(String?) for validate parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Function?` into `Function(String)?`

Comment: thanks a lot 
but this solved the on onsubmit Function error 
and validate Function error still exist.